# Configure multiple databases on reportico in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, reportico

I am having a realy hard time trying to configure a project that i have created in reportico using yii2 framework and it keeps throwing a connection error.

This is the error that i keep on getting

> Error: Error in Connection to pdo_oci database :Connection attempt
>   failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12545: Connect
>   failed because target host or object does not exist
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:640)

Below is the code for my config file for the project that I have created in reportico.

```php
<?php
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -- Reportico -----------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Module : config.php
//
// General User Configuration Settings for Reportico Operation
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Password required to gain access to the project
define('SW_PROJECT_PASSWORD', '');

// Location of Reportico Top Level Directory From Browser Point of View
define('SW_HTTP_BASEDIR', './loans');
define('SW_HTTP_URLHOST', 'http://127.0.0.1');
define('SW_DEFAULT_PROJECT', 'reports');

// Project Title used at the top of menus
define('SW_PROJECT_TITLE', 'Loan Report');

// Identify whether to always run in into Debug Mode
define('SW_ALLOW_OUTPUT', true);
define('SW_ALLOW_DEBUG', true);

// Identify whether Show Criteria is default option
define('SW_DEFAULT_SHOWCRITERIA', false);

// Specification of Safe Mode. Turn on SAFE mode by specifying true.
// In SAFE mode, design of reports is allowed but Code and SQL Injection
// are prevented. This means that the designer prevents entry of potentially
// cdangerous ustom PHP source in the Custom Source Section or potentially
// dangerous SQL statements in Pre-Execute Criteria sections
define('SW_SAFE_DESIGN_MODE',true);

// If false prevents any designing of reports
define('SW_ALLOW_MAINTAIN', true);

// Identify whether to use AJAX handling. Enabling with enable Data Pickers,
// loading of partial form elements and quicker-ti-use design mode
define('AJAX_ENABLED',true);




// Location of Reportico Top Level Directory From Browser Point of View
// DB connection details for ADODB
define('SW_DB_TYPE', '');
define('SW_DB_DRIVER','pdo_oci' );
define('SW_DB_USER', 'ebank');
define('SW_DB_PASSWORD', 'apple123');
define('SW_DB_HOST', '129.101.9.202');
define('SW_DB_DATABASE', 'MWALDEV');


define('SW_DB_CONNECT_FROM_CONFIG', true);
define('SW_DB_DATEFORMAT', 'd-m-Y');
define('SW_PREP_DATEFORMAT', 'Y-m-d');
define('SW_DB_SERVER', 'N/A');
define('SW_DB_PROTOCOL', 'N/A');
define('SW_DB_ENCODING', 'None');

//HTML Output Encoding
define('SW_OUTPUT_ENCODING', 'UTF8');

// Identify temp area
define('SW_TMP_DIR', "tmp");

// SOAP Environment
define('SW_SOAP_NAMESPACE', 'reportico.org');
define('SW_SOAP_SERVICEBASEURL', 'http://www.reportico.co.uk/swsite/site/tutorials');

// Parameter Defaults
define('SW_DEFAULT_PageSize', 'A4');
define('SW_DEFAULT_PageOrientation', 'Portrait');
define('SW_DEFAULT_TopMargin', "1cm");
define('SW_DEFAULT_BottomMargin', "2cm");
define('SW_DEFAULT_LeftMargin', "1cm");
define('SW_DEFAULT_RightMargin', "1cm");
define('SW_DEFAULT_pdfFont', "Helvetica");
define('SW_DEFAULT_pdfFontSize', "10");

// FPDF parameters
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'fpdf/font/');

// Include an image in your PDF output
// This defalt places icon top right of a portrait image and sizes it to 100 pixels wide
//define('PDF_HEADER_IMAGE', 'images/myimage.png');
//define('PDF_HEADER_XPOS', '470');
//define('PDF_HEADER_YPOS', '20');
//define('PDF_HEADER_WIDTH', '100');

// Graph Defaults
// Default Charting Engine is JpGraph. A slightly modified version 3.0.7 of jpGraph is supplied
// within Reportico.
//
// Reportico also supports pChart but the pChart package is not currently provided
// as part of the Reportico bundle. To use pChart you will need to unpack the pChart
// application into the reportico folder named pChart. pChart 2.1.3
// You can get pChart from http://www.pchart.net/
//
define("SW_GRAPH_ENGINE", "PCHART" );
if ( !defined("SW_GRAPH_ENGINE") || SW_GRAPH_ENGINE == "JPGRAPH" )
{
    define('SW_DEFAULT_Font', "Arial");
//advent_light
//Bedizen
//Mukti_Narrow
//calibri
//Forgotte
//GeosansLight
//MankSans
//pf_arma_five
//Silkscreen
//verdana
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphWidth', 800);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphHeight', 400);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphWidthPDF', 500);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphHeightPDF', 250);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphColor', "white");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginTop', "40");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginBottom', "90");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginLeft', "60");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginRight', "50");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginColor', "white");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTickLabelInterval', "1");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTickLabelInterval', "2");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTickInterval', "1");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTickInterval', "1");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GridPosition', "back");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XGridDisplay', "none");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XGridColor', "gray");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YGridDisplay', "none");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YGridColor', "gray");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleFontStyle', "Normal");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleFontSize', "12");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleColor', "black");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleFontStyle', "Normal");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleFontSize', "10");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleColor', "black");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleFontStyle', "Normal");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleFontSize', "10");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleColor', "black");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFontStyle', "Normal");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFontSize', "10");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFontColor', "black");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisColor', "black");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFontStyle', "Normal");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFontSize', "8");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFontColor', "black");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisColor', "black");
}
else // Use jpgraph
{
    define('SW_DEFAULT_Font', "Mukti_Narrow.ttf");
//advent_light.ttf
//Bedizen.ttf
//calibri.ttf
//Forgotte.ttf
//GeosansLight.ttf
//MankSans.ttf
//pf_arma_five.ttf
//Silkscreen.ttf
//verdana.ttf
    define('SW_DEFAULT_FontSize', "8");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_FontColor', "#303030");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_LineColor', "#303030");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_BackColor', "#eeeeff");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_FontStyle', "Normal");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphWidth', 800);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphHeight', 400);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphWidthPDF', 500);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphHeightPDF', 300);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GraphColor', SW_DEFAULT_BackColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginTop', "50");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginBottom', "80");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginLeft', "70");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginRight', "40");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_MarginColor', SW_DEFAULT_BackColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTickLabelInterval', "AUTO");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTickLabelInterval', "2");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTickInterval', "1");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTickInterval', "1");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_GridPosition', "back");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XGridDisplay', "none");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XGridColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YGridDisplay', "none");
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YGridColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleFontStyle', SW_DEFAULT_FontStyle);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleFontSize', 12);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_TitleColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleFontStyle', SW_DEFAULT_FontStyle);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleFontSize', SW_DEFAULT_FontSize);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XTitleColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleFontStyle', SW_DEFAULT_FontStyle);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleFontSize', SW_DEFAULT_FontSize);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YTitleColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFontStyle', SW_DEFAULT_FontStyle);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFontSize', SW_DEFAULT_FontSize);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisFontColor', SW_DEFAULT_FontColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_XAxisColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFont', SW_DEFAULT_Font);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFontStyle', SW_DEFAULT_FontStyle);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFontSize', SW_DEFAULT_FontSize);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisFontColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
    define('SW_DEFAULT_YAxisColor', SW_DEFAULT_LineColor);
}

// Automatic addition of parameter SW_LANGUAGE
define('SW_LANGUAGE', 'en_gb');
?>
```

Comment: you should hide your db password .. .. but the error  message you show  is from Yii2??'  .. and which  yii2 template you are using (basic or advanced)?

Comment: Thats not my password....am using yii2 advanced

Comment: then if you are using yii2 advanced  could you show me the content of config/main.php (or main-local.php)  components --> db section content

Comment: this is'nt related to yii2 please share your `common/config/main.php`

Answer (score 0):

db connection not configured properly.  By default, in the advanced app template the /common/config/main-local.php file holds your db settings